# Paypal automatic refund from IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

having an issue.
I want a way to do a paypal transaction automatically when the paypal IPN sends a notifications.

To give some context.
I am developing a online seat booking system (school plays etc.) and have implemented a paypal button to buy the seats once you click your seats but i want to have a way for the paypal transaction to timeout so that the booked seats can be made available again if the payment doesn't go through.
so what i have currently is a time stamp on the booked seats that gives 10 mins before they are available again. But the paykey (i think i have that right) is still valid. so the first person could (in theory) go back and pay for the seats, therefor the seats are booked out twice.
so on my IPN i have a check to see if the booking is timed out.
And this is where i am, what code can i use to issue a refund in that case?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call paypal refund API:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/refund-payment/

I would also suggest that you have check on your website when someone clicks on Pay to see if the session is expired so that payment is never done. If you implement the solution where you will call refund based on ipn you will end up paying transaction fees anyways and customer experience will also be below par.

Comment: I already have something that stops them from booking again for the same seats. but its the 1 in 1000 chance of someone clicking [back] to the paypal site and clicking pay

Comment: I would still suggest that handling back button click on your website will be a better idea, otherwise you can call refund api to refund the transactions.